# How to determine quickly which sheets have macros in Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

If an Excel Workbook has many sheets and some of them have macros inside, the only way I have found to determine which sheets have macro is by clicking each of them in Project Explorer (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** in VBA).

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

I answered a question recently in MSDN and ultimately wrote a blog post on it.

**Topic: Check if an Excel File has a Macro**

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/04/12/check-if-an-excel-file-has-a-macro/

You can then use `.VBComponents.Item(i).Name` with `.VBComponents.Item(i).Type` to check which "**Sheets**" have "**macros**".

**EDIT**

Technically speaking every **macro** is a piece of **code** but it's not necessary that every piece of **code** is a macro. So if you are just checking for macros then see the 1st part of the blog post and if you are checking for any code then look at the 2nd part of the blog post.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the sheets and use the following syntax:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(sheetName).CodeModule.CountOfLines <> 0 Then
```

`sheetName` being the name of the sheet.

For more advanced use, you should check this [page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) which gives more advanced examples.

Comment: Ummm, I just tested it and it works for me (printing 0 if there is no code and the number of line if there is some code). Am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes 2 things :) 1) See my last edit in my post 2) If you have “Require Variable Declaration” checked then count of lines will always be more than 0 even if there is no code because it will have "Option Explicit" on top. It's all explained in my blog post.